# Script for preventing file change or deletion on Windows share

Tags: file, powershell, share

We need to lock down all the files in a shared folder after 24 hours. Users upload files into that folder and need to be able to edit for 24 hours. After that, the files should be locked, no change or deletion. They do still have the ability to add more files to that folder though, just not change existing files.

We currently do this on a Linux share by using a cron job that sets the immutable flag on files. We need to move this share to Windows so that isn't an option.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: you could use `Set-Acl` in a scheduled task to do the same as you did with the cron job, it's more complex than adding immutable though, you'd need to edit each file individually to ensure that nobody but the administrator account or something has modify/write rights.

Comment: Much easier process would be using two shares. The first users can write, the later is read-only. A scheduled job would copy only allowed changes to the RO-share.

Comment: That is one of the options we were thinking about, just using 2 shares. Would have to change the workflow process slightly, but overall that might be a better approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So you would have to track who added a file and when. And your script needs to be polling this share 24x7. Based on the tracking data, you can change the permissions on that particular file to 'Read-only`. That would prevent further changes.You also gotta make sure that newly added files have change permissions active until rewritten by the script 24 hrs later. Pretty dirty but doable.

Comment: I noticed that even changing the "read-only" attribute didn't stop the file from being deleted. I couldn't update or rename the file, but I was still able to delete the file from that share.

Comment: You can always use the advanced security permissions on the file and set deny delete for 'Everyone'. Although I have not really researched on how to do this via PowerShell. I should be possible.